# SQL - Create Table with Crosstab

Tags: sql

I've created a crosstab of a table in SQL, and I would like to save as a new table or a temp table, but I can't get the syntax quite right.

Here is my SQL code:

TRANSFORM Max(R.timestamp) AS MaxOftimestamp
SELECT R.ride_id
FROM ride_timestamps as R
GROUP BY R.ride_id
PIVOT R.event

It gives the exact table that I want, but now I need to save it as it's own table or a temp table, and I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried:
INSERT INTO ##TempTableName FROM (TRANSFORM Max(R.timestamp) AS MaxOftimestamp SELECT R.ride_id FROM ride_timestamps as R GROUP BY R.ride_id PIVOT R.event)

Comment: I have. It gives me the error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"